# Styling/Theming Drupal 7 Content Type Record

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I developed a Content type of "Car Sales" with following fields:

1. Manufacturer
2. Model
3. Make
4. Fuel Type
5. Transmission (Manual/Automatic)
6. Color
7. Registered? (Yes/No)
8. Mileage
9. Engine Power
10. Condition (New/Reconditioned/Used)
11. Price
12. Pictures (Multiple uploads)

I have developed View of this Content Type to display list of cars. Now I want to develop a screen/view for individual Car Sale Record like this: 
[image]

Apart from arranging fields, please note that I want to embed a Picture Gallery in between. Can this be achieved through Drupal 7 Admin UI or do I need to create custom CSS and template files? If I need to edit certain template files/css, what are those? I'm using Zen Sub Theme.

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this by creating a page, and then creating a node template to accompany it. Start by creating a new node, and then record the NID for the name of the template.

Then, in your template, create a new file, and name it in the following manner: `node--[node id].tpl.php`

Then, in that file, paste in the following helper function (or you can put it in template.php if you're going to use it elsewhere in your site):

```
/**
 * Gets the resulting output of a view as an array of rows,
 * each containing the rendered fields of the view
 */
function views_get_rendered_fields($name, $display_id = NULL) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args); // remove $name
    if (count($args)) {
        array_shift($args); // remove $display_id
    }

    $view = views_get_view($name);
    if (is_object($view)) {
        if (is_array($args)) {
          $view->set_arguments($args);
        }
        if (is_string($display_id)) {
          $view->set_display($display_id);
        }
        else {
          $view->init_display();
        }
        $view->pre_execute();
        $view->execute();
        $view->render();
        //dd($view->style_plugin);
        return $view->style_plugin->rendered_fields;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Then add the following code to your template:

```
<?php
  $cars = views_get_rendered_fields('view name', 'default', [...any arguments to be passed to the view]);
  foreach ($cars as $car): ?>
    <div>Put your mockup in here. It might be helpful to run <?php die('<pre>'.print_r($car, 1).'</pre>'); ?> to see what the $car array looks like.</div>
  <?php endforeach;
?>
```

Just change the placeholders in the code to whatever you want the markup to be, and you should be set!

As I mentioned above, it's always helpful to do `<?php die('<pre>'.print_r($car,1).'</pre>'); ?>` to have a visual representation of what the array looks like printed.

I use `views_get_rendered_fields` all the time in my code because it allows me to completely customize the output of the view.

**As a Reminder:** Always clear your caches every time you create a new template.

Best of luck!